# Python to create a list in excel of all OneDrive uploads

Tags: python, excel, onedrive

is it possible to use Python in order to create a list in an Excel spreadsheet containing all filenames and file directories which have been uploaded on OneDrive?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but this question is very broad and isn't specific.  For the purposes of answering with brevity:

**OneDrive SDK for Python**

This will give you access to a OneDrive account with various methods to list both items and last modified.

URL: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python

**XlsxWriter for Python**
This will give you the ability to write files in the Excel 2007+ XLSX file format.  If you just wish Excel to be able to open the file then you could just use the standard CSV module.

URL: https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/